# creating crystal report based on a listview subitem value

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, crystal-reports, subitem

Is it possible to create a crystal report with values coming from a listview subitems which is generated after a mouse button event? I don't know how to make crystal report yet. I'm still trying to find a way to generate a report based on the listview subitems for printing. if it isn't asking too much can you please provide a link or a tutorial on how to make this.

Comment: you can not do this directly. first you have to create a report which is containing same fields as listview. then store your listview data into datatable and assign it to report document by SetDataSource method.

Comment: do i have to do this inside the same form as my listview? or can i use another form

Comment: No you do this whole process in a single form.  You need another form only to preview your report. If you don't wish to create another form then you can place crystalreportviewer control in same widow.

Comment: can i print the form with the report preview? sorry for asking too many questions i'm new with c#

Comment: You cannot do this directly in crystal report. You have to make a design first then you can assign the datasource by datatable which i have mentioned in first comment. But, if you are trying to print a form there are several methods to print your form directly without creating crystal report document. but, you are using a listview in your form so there may be a scroll bar. if you are trying to print form directly then your scroll bar will be printed also and scrolled data will not be printed. so, my suggestion is that create a Crystal Report design first.